# Disable Maximum Inheritance Depth in sonar

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I have a problem with disabling the issue "Maximum Inheritance Depth".
In the sonar rule description it is written that its squid is:
"squid:MaximumInheritanceDepth".
So, in my POM i have:

```
<sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria>e11</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria>
<sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e11.rulekey>squid:MaximumInheritanceDepth</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e11.rulekey>
<sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e11.resourceKey>**/GUIpanel.java</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e11.resourceKey>
```

But the build fails showing the following error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project parent: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.issue.ignore.scanner.IssueExclusionsLoader: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.issue.ignore.pattern.IssueExclusionPatternInitializer: Exclusions > Issues : Invalid format. The second field does not define a rule pattern: **/GUIpanel.java,,* -> [Help 1]
```

That i understand it is telling to me that the exclusion provided for the class GUIpanel it cannot be performed since the second field (the rule key) does not define a rule pattern, so it is wrong to write

```
squid:MaximumInheritanceDept
```

So, what could be the solution?

Comment: Why not disabling it in your quality profile of your project ?

Comment: because it is mandatory to disable it from the pom (it is a project for an exam) :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. ruleKey must be with capital K, I had it written as: rulekey, but it shall be ruleKey.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria>e11</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria>
    <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e11.ruleKey>squid:MaximumInheritanceDepth</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e11.ruleKey>
    <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e11.resourceKey>**/*.java</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e11.resourceKey>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <jacoco.data.file>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</jacoco.data.file>
    <jacoco.report.path>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco.xml</jacoco.report.path>
    <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${jacoco.data.file}</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
</properties>
```